# use Enum class instead of a Map for holding constants

Tags: java

I have a map like below to hold some constant values. Keeping values in a Map is not a good practice. Instead I can use an enum to hold these values.
But I'm a bit confused about how to create an enum for the below mapping

```
//Map to store the events
public static final Map<String, Integer[]> OLYMPICS_SPORT_ID_PARAMS = new HashMap<>();
public static final Map<String, Integer[]> OLYMPICS_EVENT_ID_PARAMS = new HashMap<>();
public static final Map<String, Integer[]> OLYMPICS_PHASE_ID_PARAMS = new HashMap<>();
static {
    OLYMPICS_SPORT_ID_PARAMS.put("sportId", VALID_SPORT_IDS);
    OLYMPICS_EVENT_ID_PARAMS.put("n_EventID", VALID_EVENT_IDS);
    OLYMPICS_PHASE_ID_PARAMS.put("n_EventPhaseID", VALID_EVENT_PHASE_IDS);
}

public static final Map<String, Map<String, Integer[]>> OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP = new HashMap<>();
static {
    OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP.put("sportId", OLYMPICS_SPORT_ID_PARAMS);
    OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP.put("eventId", OLYMPICS_EVENT_ID_PARAMS);
    OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP.put("eventPhaseId", OLYMPICS_PHASE_ID_PARAMS);
}
```

Any idea to create an ENUM class to map OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP ?

Comment: It's not clear from this code snippet what you're trying to model. Please provide more context.

Comment: I'd question the idea that it's "not good practice". In my experience, enums are rarely the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ENUM` class to store your constants by creating constructor and getters for the `ENUM` with body. Like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    FIRST("1", "my first"),
    SECOND("2", "my second"),
    THIRD("3", "my third");

    private final String value;
    private final String description;

    MyEnum(String value, String description) {
        this.value = value;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

And access your value or description by using: `MyEnum.FIRST.getValue();`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd define it like this

```
enum IdParams {
    OLYMPICS_SPORT_ID_PARAMS(VALID_SPORT_IDS),
    OLYMPICS_EVENT_ID_PARAMS(VALID_EVENT_IDS),
    OLYMPICS_PHASE_ID_PARAMS(VALID_EVENT_PHASE_IDS);

    private Integer[] params;
    private IdParams(Integer[] p) {
        params = p;
    }
    public Integer[] getParameters() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Be aware that an array is a very dangerous thing to have around like this though; client classes will be able to manipulate the individual values. I recommend you make it a `List<Integer>` and return an unmodifiable version:

```
    List<Integer> params; 
    // ...
    private IdParams(Integer[] p) {
        params = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(p));
    }
    public List<Integer> getParamters() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(params);
    }
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think your last snippet is still dangerous. It is still possible to change the passed array and that will influence both `params` as well as the unmodifiable list returned by `getParameters()`. `Collections.unmodifiableList` creates an unmodifiable view of the original list, not a copy.

Comment: @lexicore You're right, the `asList()` doesn't create a copy and will allow write-through from the original array. Edited the answer to create a `new ArrayList` in the constructor which will prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

The first option to replace your initial implementation would be to use an enum map, `java.util.EnumMap<K, V>`, which is aware of the enum type.

However, if you need to use an enum for this, a valid enum recording both the ID and the int array could look like:

```
enum OlympicEvents {
    OLYMPICS_EVENTS_MAP("sportId", new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }), 
    OLYMPICS_EVENT_ID_PARAMS("eventId", new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }), 
    OLYMPICS_PHASE_ID_PARAMS("eventPhaseId", new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 });


    private String eventId;

    private Integer[] eventParams;

    private OlympicEvents (String eventId, Integer[] eventParams) {

        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.eventParams = eventParams;
    }

    public String getEventId() {

        return eventId;
    }

    public Integer[] getEventParams() {

        return eventParams;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my HO, generally you want to write the statement like this:

```
OlimpicSportEvent olSpEv = new OlimpicSportEvent(
                Sport.ATHLETIC, Event.SPRINT_100_M, Phase.SEMIFINAL);
```

To be able to do so, you have to be sure that your `Event.SPRINT_100_M` have `Phase.SEMIFINAL` **AND** `Sport.ATHLETIC` have `Event.SPRINT_100_M`.

I'll not write the entire code here, but I'd try to explain my approach.
First of all, you should write *not only one*, but **three** enums. I hope the code will tell you more than words. E.g.

```
public enum Sport {
    ATHLETIC    (0,
                Arrays.asList(  Event.SPRINT_100_M,
                                Event.MARATHON)
                ),
    //...
    SOCCER      (109,
                Arrays.asList(  Event.TEAM_MATCH)
                );

    private final int id;
    private final List<Event> events;

    Sport(int id, List<Event> events){
        this.id = id;
        this.events = events;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    protected List<Event> getEvents(){
        return this.events;
    }

}

enum Event {
    SPRINT_100_M, // similar to enum Sport, params goes here
    //...
    TEAM_MATCH,
    MARATHON;
}

enum Phase {
    FIRST_ROUND, // params goes here
    //...
    SEMIFINAL,
    FINAL
}
```

As you see, I only wrote the `enum Sport` to the end.
Now, I wrote 'test' sample like this (note that you **must** implement the validate method to meet your request as well as you **must** write the complete code for `Event` and `Phase` enums...

```
public class Answer {

    static class OlimpicSportEvent {
        //private other field 
        //private other field 
        private final Sport sport;
        private final Event event;
        private final Phase phase;

        OlimpicSportEvent(Sport sport, Event event, Phase phase) throws Exception{
            this.sport = sport;
            this.event = event;
            this.phase = phase;

            if(!this.validate()){
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public Sport getSport() {
            return sport;
        }

        public Event getEvent() {
            return event;
        }

        public Phase getPhase() {
            return phase;
        }

        private boolean validate(){
            return this.sport.getEvents().contains(this.event);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            OlimpicSportEvent olSpEv = new OlimpicSportEvent(
                    Sport.ATHLETIC, Event.SPRINT_100_M, Phase.SEMIFINAL);
            System.out.println("olSpEv created!");
            // do whatever you want
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("olSpEv invalid!");
            // handle ex
        }

    }

}
```